# Where to view Google Cloud messaging for Android reports and request details

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Where to view Google Cloud messaging for Android reports and request details

Some of message i'm receiving from GCM and some not, so i want to see the reports or api access list in google console. Where can i see this details

Source code i used

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, Stats on the Google API Console are not enabled for GCM. The GCM Stats are only available on the [Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/) (which costs $25 to register to).

> Viewing Statistics
>
> To view statistics and any error messages for your GCM applications:
>
> ```
> 1. Go to the Developer Console.
> 2. Login with your developer account.
>    You will see a page that has a list of all of your apps.
> 3. Click on the "statistics" link next to the app for which you want to view GCM
>    stats. Now you are on the statistics page.
> 4. Go to the drop-down menu and select the GCM metric you want to view.
> ```
>
> Note: Stats on the Google API Console are not enabled for GCM. You
>   must use the Developer Console.

([Source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#stats))